# This Field can not be changed Django Validation Error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

All
I am trying to create valiadtion check that will check after saving the "Name" and "Address that field can not be changed,
How I can do that?

```
class Institution(CustomModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256,
                        null=False,
                        blank=False,
                        verbose_name=_('Name'))
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address',
                            on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                            null=False,
                            blank=False,
                            verbose_name=_('Address'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by cannot be changed, once saved that you can't change it again?

Comment: Hi, Yes after saving only those values can not be change

Answer (score 1):

only you need is setting `editable=False` in your model
[Check the Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#editable)